# Unexpected behavior - Async Await when required with IIFE?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, iife

I've two nodejs files, in which async-await doesn't work, if I `require` a node module *(test2.js)* which has IIFE defined in it.

### test1.js

```
async function abc() {
    console.log(1)
    let computeFunction = await require("./test2");
    console.log(4)
    computeFunction()
    return null;
}

(async () => { await abc() })()
```

### test2.js

> The idea here is to export a function which does some computations,
>   but before exporting, I need to initialize database connections so that the computation function will work properly.

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async () => {
    console.log(2)
    // some connection initialization
    await sleep(1000)
    console.log(3)
    return null;
})()

module.exports = async () => {
    // does some computation with those connections
    console.log(5)
    return null;
}
```

### Output

**Actual**

```
1
2
4
5
3
```

**Expected**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

> I figured other solution by not using IIFE, but I want to know why async-await won't work when requiring a module which has an IIFE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very wrong statement `async-await won't work when requiring a module which has an IIFE`. 
Actual output is different from the expected output because of `synchronous nature of require` not because of IIFE.

You can get output in the order of `1,2,3(after waiting for 1000ms), 4 ,5`  if you use any asynchronous require function.

Check this:-

**test1.js**

```
const asyncRequire = require('./async-require');

async function abc() {
    console.log(1)
    let computeFunction = await asyncRequire("./test2.js");
    console.log(4)
    computeFunction()
    return null;
}

(async () => { await abc() })();
```

**test2.js**

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

await (async () => {
    console.log(2)
    // some connection initialization
    await sleep(1000)
    console.log(3)
    return null;
})();

module.exports = async () => {
    // does some computation with those connections
    console.log(5)
    return null;
}
```

**async-require.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = async path=>{
    return new Promise((success, fail)=>{
        fs.readFile(path, async (error, file)=>{
            const myModule = {};
            await eval(`(async (module)=>{ ${file.toString()} })(myModule);`);
            success(myModule.exports);
        }); 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have used `Promise()` inside he `async/await` . but `async/await` itself returns the promised value . check out my code and also have a look at the demo .

```js
async function abc() {
  try {
    console.log(1)
    let computeFunction = await hey();
    console.log(4)
    return null;
  } catch (e) {}
}

(async function() {
  await abc()
})();


function sleep() {
  console.log("do some cool stuff"); //make your database connection . 
}

function hey() {
  try {
    (async() => {
      console.log(2)
      // some connection initialization
      await sleep()
      console.log(3)
      return true;
    })()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: over here youve assumed sleep as DB initialization function, which should be a promise

Comment: Yes it as assumed as DB initialisation , which will return promise itself . try out the code . @MukeshSuthar

Comment: your code doesn't work in sync if I write some time-consuming code in your sleep function

Comment: Then you can also make that time consuming code `await` . Write `async` before `sleep()`   and write await wherever your time consuming code is . @MukeshSuthar

Comment: if i change your sleep function with mine, your code doesnt work.
here sleep is time-consuming promise.